# Emulate dynamic scoping in R to filter by arbitrary functions

Tags: r, higher-order-functions, scoping

I have a number of files in a directory, and I want to distribute them between two newly created subdirectories based on whether their content satisfies a certain condition. Moreover, I need to perform this operation on multiple directories, and each time, the condition might be different.

The way I thought I would go about this was to create a higher-order function that reads in the files, extracts the property of interest from each, and then applies the condition (supplied as an argument in the form of a function) element-wise to the resulting vector of values:

```
filter.by.property <- function(where, funct) {
  setwd(where)
  paths <- list.files(".", pattern = ".file")
  Robjects <- Map(read.file, paths)
  values <- sapply(Robjects, function(x) property_of_interest(x))
  passes <- Filter(funct, paths)
  dir.create("dir1")
  dir.create("dir2")
  file.copy(passes, paste("./dir1/", 1:length(passes), ".file", sep = ""))
  file.copy(paths[!paths %in% passes], paste("./dir2/", (length(passes) + 1):length(paths), ".file", sep = ""))
}
```

The problem is that I would like the condition-specifying function (supplied in the `funct` argument) to have access to the `values` vector. For example:

```
ten.biggest <- function(path) {
  Robject <- read.file(path)
  property_of_interest(x) %in% tail(sort(values), 10)
}

filter.by.property(<place>, ten.biggest)
```

Since R is lexically scoped, it will look for `values` in the environment where `ten.biggest` is defined (the global environment) rather than in the environment where it is called (i.e., inside `filter.by.property`). I could solve this by using global assignment for `values` inside `filter.by.property`, but I'd prefer not to do that unless absolutely necessary. I could also supply `values` as another argument to `ten.biggest`, but then the function would no longer be unary, and I'm not sure how (or even whether) it could still be used inside `Filter`.

One solution I attempted was to rewrite `ten.biggest` as follows

```
ten.biggest <- function(path) {
  Robject <- read.file(path)
  property_of_interest(x) %in% tail(sort(eval.parent(parse(text = values))), 10)
}
```

but that didn't work.

Is there any way to I can emulate dynamic scoping in R to make this work? From reading related StackExchange questions, it seems that perhaps the `body` function could help, but I don't know how to apply it to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that doesn't rely on switching environments. I allowed `ten.biggest` to take two arguments, and defined a helper function, `outer_fxn`, right inside `filter.by.property` to convert a binary function into a unary function by setting one of its arguments. The binary `ten.biggest` function can then be passed to `filter.by.property` via the latter's `funct` argument, the `vals` argument of `ten.biggest` is set to `values` by `outer_fxn`, and the resulting unary function can then be used inside `Filter`:

```
ten.biggest <- function(path, vals) {
  Robject <- read.file(path)
  property_of_interest(x) %in% tail(sort(vals), 10)
}

filter.by.property <- function(where, funct) {
  setwd(where)
  paths <- list.files(".", pattern = ".file")
  Robjects <- Map(read.file, paths)
  values <- sapply(Robjects, function(x) property_of_interest(x))
  outer_fxn <- function(x) { funct(x, values) }
  passes <- Filter(outer_fxn, paths)
  dir.create("dir1")
  dir.create("dir2")
  file.copy(passes, paste("./dir1/", 1:length(passes), ".file", sep = ""))
  file.copy(paths[!paths %in% passes], paste("./dir2/", (length(passes) + 1):length(paths), ".file", sep = ""))
}
```